# Reading JSON from local file with Clojure?

Tags: json, clojure

Im pretty clear on how to parse JSON from http requests. But I have a JSON file locally I would like to use within my code.

I have tried to find a solution on google but I am struggling to figure out how to read a local JSON file from the file system

Thanks

Vinn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [clojure/data.json](https://github.com/clojure/data.json) library:

- Add this dependency into `project.clj`:

`[org.clojure/data.json "2.4.0"]`

- Add this requirement into namespace definition:

`(:require [clojure.data.json :as json])`

- Then use [`read-str`](https://clojure.github.io/data.json/#clojure.data.json/read-str) with [`slurp`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/slurp). I made example file `filename.json` with this content:

```
{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}
```

and read it like this:

```
(json/read-str (slurp "filename.json"))
=> {"name" "John", "age" 30, "car" nil}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what's the difference between a json arriving from an http request and a json arriving from a local file? I suppose the real question then is "how to read from a local file", no?

Here is how to read a json from a string using [clojure/data.json](https://github.com/clojure/data.json):

```clj
(def json-str (json/read-str "{\"a\":1,\"b\":{\"c\":\"d\"}}"))
```

Now, lets put the same string into a file

```bash
echo '{"a":1,"b":{"c":"d"}}' > /tmp/a.json
```

And lets read it from the file:

```clj
(def from-file (slurp "/tmp/a.json"))
(def json-file (json/read-str from-file))
```

Make sure they are the same:

```clj
(when (= json-str json-file)
  (println "same" json-file))
```

Which would print "same" and the parsed json value.

Answer (score 0):

In clojure you can use the dep:

```
cheshire {:mvn/version "5.10.1"}
```

import the class:

```
:require
[cheshire.core :as json]
```

and use this function and return you a mapp

```
(defn read-invoice [file-path]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader file-path)]
    (json/parse-stream rdr true)))
```